# Api.ai send email from php webhook

Tags: php, heroku, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I have a php webhook, Im hosting it on Heroku, evertyhing works fine. When I test it on api.ai the bot answers me the way that I want, so its working. My question is: How can I send an email from my webhook or insert the text on a Database?
Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
//$msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
//$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

// send email
//mail("moscosisi@gmail.com","My subject",$msg);


// Process only when method is POST
if($method == 'POST'){

$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($requestBody);

$equis = $json->result->parameters->equis;

switch ($equis) {
    case 'hi':
        $speech = "Hi, Nice to meet you";

        break;

    case 'bye':
        $speech = "Bye, good night";
        break;

    case 'anything':
        $speech = "Yes, you can type anything here.";
        break;

    default:
        $speech = "Sorry, I didnt get that. Please ask me something 
else.";
        break;
}


$response = new \stdClass();
$response->speech = $speech;
$response->displayText = $speech;
$response->source = "Alex";

echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
echo "Method not allowed";
}

?>
```

Comment: Is the email being sent to you by the callback as a param and this is a *how do I send email in PHP* question or Is it a *how do I match an email in the context action*?

Comment: btw fulfillments are for when you have collected the data or need to query additional data, not for basic bot responses they should be done with intents.

Comment: I want to send $spech on an email but I dont know how can I do that

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have most of the parts put together that you need. After you've figured out what you want `$speech` to be, you can use the parts you've commented out to send the message. Perhaps something like this:

```
switch ($equis) {
    case 'hi':
        $speech = "Hi, Nice to meet you";

        break;

    case 'bye':
        $speech = "Bye, good night";
        break;

    case 'anything':
        $speech = "Yes, you can type anything here.";
        break;

    default:
        $speech = "Sorry, I didnt get that. Please ask me something 
else.";
        break;
}

mail("moscosisi@gmail.com","My subject",$msg);
```

Similarly, you can do database operations or whatever else you want with the values you get from the parameters sent from Dialogflow.

The more confusing part about this is that you don't seem to be paying attention to what Intent or Action was fired. This would be in

```
$json->result->action
```

or

```
$json->result->metadata->intentName
```

Typically you use one of these to figure out *why* you're being called, and then the parameters to figure out what to do based on that.